# how do I get all the objects associated with a foreignkey field

Tags: python, django

How do I get all the objects associated with the foreignkey field in "ProductImage". So I've multiple images for one "Product" model in "ProductImage", how do I get all of the associated ones. Currently, I'm getting an error "MultipleObjectsReturned at /shop/product-slug" idk what I'm doing wrong, would appreciate it a lot if someone can help! thx!

models.py

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    description = models.TextField()
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)


class ProductImage(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to='productimg/')
```

urls.py

```
path("<slug:slug>", views.detail_view, name="detail_view"),
```

views.py

```
def detail_view(request, slug): 
    products = Product.objects.get(slug=slug)
    productimg = ProductImage.objects.get(product=products)
```

Comment: just change `get` method to `filter` on your second query, then you will obtain a query set of all images associated to the selected product, you can iterate through it in a for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find all related objects in **Django**, use `filter` method that returns a queryset, use `get` method instead if you know there is only one object that matches your query.

Read more in the [official **Django** documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-a-single-object-with-get)

**Another tip**: when using `get`, it's highly recommended you surround it with `try` `except` block in order to make your code brokenless if the selected object is not found. Your code could be like that :

```
def detail_view(request, slug):
  try:
    products = Product.objects.get(slug=slug)
    productimg = ProductImage.objects.filter(product=products)
  except Product.DoesNotExist as e:
    print(f"My error {e}")
    # ... other error handling

  for image in  productimg :
    # your logic here
```